# unable to call a function inside an iter chain in python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I am using the following iter chain, to generate a list -

```
from itertools import chain
from utils import my_func // custom function written that performs a function.
a = list(chain.from_iterable((u, my_func(u)) for u in MyCustomClass.objects.all()))
```

I expect that a list will be generated. 
But then, I get the error - `NameError: global name 'my_func' is not defined`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the whole error message with full traceback.  Is the error actually generated by that line?

Comment: this is all that I have got, in the ipython shell.

Comment: Does just typing `my_func` work in the shell, or does that too give a name error?

Comment: Are you using this with Django? Also can you provide the utils.py file?

Comment: After doing `from utils import my_func`, the name `my_func` _is_ defined as a global name. So, the snippet you pasted cannot be generating the reported error. Since you say this happened at the ipython shell, could it have been a typo somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Django/iPython there is a bug with Django: iPython is started with a different namespace, which could explain your problem.

You can try to use a different shell (base `python` or bpython) or try to [patch](https://github.com/django/django/commit/3570ff734e93f493e023b912c9a97101f605f7f5#django/core/management/commands/shell.py) your Django installation. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16617975/1205368) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try utils.func(), could be that the function is out of the current scope